# How to determine if .bashrc running inside VSCode terminal or not

Tags: linux, bash, shell, visual-studio-code

I'd like to see if .bashrc is running inside the VSCode terminal.

I'm adding some aliases and doing some customization in my .bashhrc that I want to be applied also inside the VSCode terminal, but I don't want the last line in my script, "cd /var/myrepo," to happen because I want the terminal to stay in the current directory when opened inside VSCode.

which condition can I specify inside .bashrc to ignore some commands while running inside VSCode terminal?

Comment: just add a environment variable. and echo it.

Comment: @rɑːdʒɑ How to add the variable only for VSCode terminal?

Comment: for Windows VSC looks like it sets `TERM_PROGRAM=vscode`, look in your terminal for a similar environment variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the variable `TERM_PROGRAM` equals to `vscode`.